# How to fill empty cells in gpplot2 for absent data

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I created this heatmap in R with ggplot2
[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZeM4.png)

I'd like to add empty tiles borders for the empty observations, but these values are absent in my dataset, which has the following structure :

| Shop | Day | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | 4 |
| 01 | 02 | 2 |
| 01 | 05 | 3 |
| 02 | 01 | 1 |
| 03 | 03 | 2 |

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an empty tibble with the structure you need and join in the real data. For example,

```
fake_dat <- crossing(Shop = 1:3, Day = 1:20)
plot_dat <- left_join(fake_dat, real_dat, by=c("Shop","Day")

ggplot(plot_dat, aes(Day, Shop)) %>%
    geom_tile(color="black") %>%
    geom_label(aes(label=Sales))
```